# Start web browser with page

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to start the default system web browser with configured web page.

```
    MenuItem hc = new MenuItem("Help Contents");

    hc.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // Start Web Browser with page google.com
        }
    });
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to do it would be with:

```
String location_url = "http://www.google.com/";
            try {     
                try {
                      Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(location_url));
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
```

It's technically an awt library, so you'll need the following imports:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
```